# Grammar Induction Program - Squitor

Tags: algorithm, context-free-grammar, grammar-induction

Does anyone know of a program that does grammar induction? For example, where can I find the source code for the REQUITER Context Free Grammar program?

Answer (score 2):

There are several implementations of the [Sequitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequitur_algorithm) (or Neville-Manning) algorithm available [here](http://sequitur.info/). The page appears to be maintained by [Neville-Manning and Witten](http://sequitur.info/jair/), and links to implementations of the Sequitor algorithm in [C++](http://sequitur.info/sequitur_simple.cc) and [Java](http://sequitur.info/java/).

There is a C# implementation of the [Lempel-Ziv-Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZW) algorithm called [SharpLZW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharplzw/). The Lempel-Ziv-Welch and Sequitor algorithms both deterministically construct context-free grammars and are very efficient. The specific application you intend might require a different type of algorithm, however.

The majority of the research on grammar induction that I have encountered focuses on genetic algorithms. Unfortunately, I am unqualified to comment on them. Perhaps someone else can.